# Read bincode serialized structs in parallel from file

Tags: rust, serde, bincode

I am currently using `serde-jsonlines` to serialize a large number of identical structs to file. I am then using `rayon` to read data out of this file in parallel using `par_bridge`:

```
let mut reader = JsonLinesReader::new(input_file);    
let results: Vec<ResultStruct> = db_json_reader
                .read_all::<MyStruct>()
                .par_bridge()
                .into_par_iter()
                .map(|my_struct| {
                    // do processing of my struct and return result
                    result
                })
                .collect();
```

This works since `JsonLinesReader` returns an iterator over the lines of the input file. I'd like to use `bincode` to encode my structs instead as this results in a smaller file on disk. I have the following playground that works as expected:

```
use bincode;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    name: String,
    value: Vec<u64>,
}

pub fn playground() {
    let s1 = MyStruct {
        name: "Hello".to_string(),
        value: vec![1, 2, 3],
    };
    let s2 = MyStruct {
        name: "World!".to_string(),
        value: vec![3, 4, 5, 6],
    };

    let out_file = File::create("test.bin").expect("Unable to create file");
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(out_file);

    let s1_encoded: Vec<u8> = bincode::serialize(&s1).unwrap();
    writer.write_all(&s1_encoded).expect("Unable to write data");

    let s2_encoded: Vec<u8> = bincode::serialize(&s2).unwrap();
    writer.write_all(&s2_encoded).expect("Unable to write data");

    drop(writer);

    let mut in_file = File::open("test.bin").expect("Unable to open file");
    let s1_decoded: MyStruct =
        bincode::deserialize_from(&mut in_file).expect("Unable to read data");
    let s2_decoded: MyStruct =
        bincode::deserialize_from(&mut in_file).expect("Unable to read data");

    println!("s1_decoded: {:?}", s1_decoded);
    println!("s2_decoded: {:?}", s2_decoded);
}
```

Is it possible to read the structs out in parallel in a manner similar to what I am currently doing with `serde-jsonlines`? I imagine this might not be possible since each struct is not terminated by a newline and thus there is no sensible way to chunk up the input stream to allow processing by multiple threads.

Comment: I can't remember for sure, but I think the bincode spec is length-preceded frames for each value. If you can confirm it is, you may be able to read a length, and slice each value from the original message, and then process each value in parallel after finding value boundaries.

Comment: Note that your JSON code uses a single thread to parse the JSON and only goes multithread for the processing, so there's no reason why the same couldn't be done with the bincode.

Comment: I.e. something like `iter::from_fn (move || bincode::deserialize_from(&mut in_file).ok()).par_bridge()…` should work.

Comment: OT: You don't need to `.par_bridge().into_par_iter()` that's just the same as `.par_bridge()`

Comment: Important question for these kind of things: did you benchmark that reading in parallel is actually faster? I have the intuition that your problem is IO bound, and hence adding more threads wont make a difference. The only thing that can speed it up is upgrading to a faster drive.

Comment: Thanks @Jmb and @cafce25. I had indeed misunderstood how `par_bridge()` works. I was not aware of `iter::from_fn` and your proposal does exactly what I was looking for @Jmb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the `serde-jsonlines` code uses a single thread to parse the JSON, and only goes multithread for the `map` processing. The same thing can be done with `bincode`:

```
let results: Vec<ResultStruct> = iter::from_fn (
        move || bincode::deserialize_from (&mut in_file).ok())
    .par_bridge()
    .map (|my_struct| {
        // do processing of my struct and return result
        result
    })
    .collect();
```

(I also removed the redundant call to `into_par_iter` since `par_bridge` already creates a parallel iterator).